# MongoClient on error event

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Node/Mongo and want to capture all MongoErrors so that I can transform then into another error format. I am looking to do this at the base level but cannot figure it out.

Here's my connection setup:

```
let connection = false

// Create a Mongo connection
export function getConnection () {
  if (!connection) {
    connection = MongoClient.connect(config.db.mongo.uri, {
      promiseLibrary: Promise //Bluebird
    })
  }

  return connection
}

// Fetch a connection for a collection
export function getCollection (collection) {
  return getConnection().then(c =>
     c.collection(collection)
  )
}
```

I've tried adding `on('error')` to both `connection` and `MongoClient` as well as `MongoClient.Db` but they do not have that method. I've additionally  added a `catch` block to my `getCollection` but the errors do not seem to hit it (I am testing with the MongoError 11000 for duplicate fields.

It seems that it can be [done](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#event:error) but haven't figured it out. It may be because I am using promises.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code does it for us. I suspect you need to pass in the function that handles the 'error' event as well. Hope it helps someone who stumbles across this question in the future.

```
MongoClient.connect(database_string, (err, db) => {
  this.db.on('error', function() {
  console.error("Lost connection to mongodb(error), exiting".bold.red);
  return process.exit(1);
}); // deal breaker for now
}
```